# Python: ctypes and garbage collection

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have following code snippets
Code illustrates matrix (2D array) with dynamic allocation

## C

```
int** create_matrix(int r, int c)
{
    int i, j, count;

    int **arr = (int **)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));


    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
       for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
          arr[i][j] = ++count;  

    return arr;
}
```

## Python ( Call C function)

```
r = 3
c = 3
p_int = POINTER(POINTER(c_int))
testlib.create_matrix.restype = POINTER(POINTER(c_int))
p_int = testlib.create_matrix(r, c) #does p_int and inner array deallocated automatically in python?
```

My Questions are:

1. Does python/ctypes handles de-allocation of memory allocated by C?
2. If we require it to de-allocate manually then how? Calling free or something else?

   - any blog or post which clarifies same would be great

Comment: Why do you have the line `p_int = POINTER(POINTER(c_int))`? That's not doing anything useful.

Comment: ctypes won't `free` the array of pointers, nor the rows.  First and foremost, it doesn't own the memory, so that would be a terrible idea. Plus it doesn't know `p_int` points at an array of pointers, nor the length of the array, so how could it know it needs to call free `r+1` times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does python/ctypes handles de-allocation of memory allocated by C?

If your code calls `malloc()`; it is your responsibility to call the code that calls `free()`.

> If we require it to de-allocate manually then how? Calling free or something else?
>   any blog or post which clarifies same would be great

C code should provide the complementary `free_matrix()` function that should be called by the code that calls `create_matrix()`. There are plenty of implementations of `free_matrix()`, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13023927/4279).

You could wrap `create_matrix()`, `free_matrix()` into an object and call `free_matrix()` in its `__del__()` method. And/or if you want more deterministic approach (the time `__del__()` is called or whether it is called at all depends on the implementation); you could create a context manager:

```
from contextlib import contexmanager

@contextmanager
def matrix():
    m = Matrix() # calls create_matrix() internally
    try:
        yield m # Matrix() may protect against out-of-bound error
    finally:
        m.clear() # call free_matrix()
```

Example:

```
with matrix() as m:
   print(m[0][1])
```

Comment: +1, but if at all possible, a library should let the client allocate aggregate data. In that case the OP can use a ctypes array such as `p_int = (c_int * c * r)()` that's reference counted by the interpreter.

Comment: @eryksun: yes. Accepting a pre-allocated buffer is a good option. Note: use `((c_int * c) * r)` for clarity, to avoid confusion with `(c_int * (c * r))`.

Comment: I generally avoid parentheses to clarify order of operations and binary operations unless it's a particularly convoluted expression. I thought the evaluation of `c_int * c * r` was self-evident.

Comment: @eryksun: given that `*` is associative operator in most contexts, unlike in this case; the parentheses are warranted even if you yourself always remember what the right interpretation is.